# calling __dopostback() from javascript cases full postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have update panel inside which I am using a control that does a postback to the server... I rather would like to call the `__dopostback ('controlid','')` in javascript. 
I have put the controls id in the trigger section of the updatepanel. However, the when the the __dopostback in javascript is called the it does full postback. I used both the `'<%= Control.ClientID %>'` and hard coded client side id but the behaviour is unstable.
the snippet is below.

```
   if (FriendsNotificationsrefreshed == false) {
             currentvalue = intvalue;
             requestsdiv.innerHTML = intvalue.toString();
             requestsdiv.style.display = "block";
             __doPostBack('ctl00_PanelHead2', '');
             FriendsNotificationsrefreshed = true;
         }
```

Comment: `PanelHead` seems to be a panel. You need to pass a control-id that is registered as async postback trigger on the UpdatePanel. So for example: `__doPostBack('<%= AsyncButton.ClientID %>','');`.

Comment: I think I mentioned in the question that I have registered the event as async postback `<Triggers>
                                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PanelHead2" EventName="Click" />
                                            </Triggers>`